# How to define span tag within an option of a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using HAML to create a drop down list as shown below:

```
%select.categories
  %option{:category => 'question'}
    Top Questions in
    %span#topic-name
  %option{:category => 'muse'}
    Top Muses in
    %span#topic-name
  %option{:category => 'user'}
    Top Users in
    %span#topic-name
.clear
```

My intention is to add the topic name to the span id 'topic-name'. However when I try to find the span using jQuery $('#topic-name'), an empty array was returned.

I checked the generated HTML and I was not able to see the span tags defined

[image]

Can anyone advise me on how I can create a span with the purpose of adding a 'topic name'

Thanks

Comment: So is there any way I can dynamically add a topic name to an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rory McCrossan said, you cannot have a `span` inside of an `option`. It is invalid HTML.

You can however find the `Option` you want to modify and use JQuery's `.append()` function to insert the new text.

For example:

```
%select.categories
    %option{:id =>'optQuestion', :category => 'question'}
        Top Questions in
```

The JQuery to add text would be

```
$('optQuestion').append("some text"); // where "some text" is what you want to insert
```

If you have multiple copies of the same `select` and want to update them all with the same "some text" you can use a class instead of an ID for your targeting.

Answer (score 2):

HTML cannot be inserted inside option elements - only text. What you are asking cannot be achieved.

Alternatively, you could add the topic name as a `data-x` parameter, although this would only be valid in HTML5. I don't know how to achieve this in HAML, but the HTML would look like:

```
<select>
    <option data-topicname="ABC">Top Questions in</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but how do I add a topic name text to the back of the string 'Top Questions in'?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to use a plugin which simulates combobox behavior. I don't know about for jQuery, but ExtJS components have capabilities like that--but they're not provided by standard HTML and CSS as Rory mentioned.

This might be a good starting point:

http://www.designdim.com/2011/07/10-important-jquery-selectboxdropdown-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

you ca use optgroup html tag

see docu here

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_optgroup_label.asp

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a good candidate for an [`optgroup`](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/optgroup/) which allows for a non-selectable "header" option and groups its enclosed options together.